# Pandas groupby aggregating by columns the sum() only provides a count using lambda

Tags: pandas, lambda, sum, aggregate

I have been trying to aggregate multiple columns in a groupby using lambda functions to select which rows to sum().  The problem I have is that the sum() only provides a count. I am very mediocre at pandas and have searched but not located an answer. Any answer would highly appreciate and I do certainly appreciate your time.

```
groupedByEmployeeShift['Duration1'] = groupedByEmployeeShift['Duration']  ### create a dummy column for ShiftOT below
groupedByEmployeeShift['RoundedInMinutes1'] = groupedByEmployeeShift['RoundedInMinutes']  ### create a dummy column for RoundedInMinutes below
groupedByEmployeeShift['RoundedOutMinutes1'] = groupedByEmployeeShift['RoundedOutMinutes']  ### create a dummy column for RoundedOutMinutes below

shiftStats = groupedByEmployeeShift.groupby('employee').agg(
    WorkLocation = ('WorkedLocation', 'first'),
    AllShifts = ('Duration', 'count'),
    OTShifts = ('Duration1', lambda x: (x > 8).sum()),
    NoRoundedInMinutes = ('RoundedInMinutes', lambda x: (x == 0).sum()),
    NoRoundedOutMinutes = ('RoundedOutMinutes', lambda x: (x == 0).sum()),
    RoundedInMinutes = ('RoundedInMinutes1', lambda x: (x > 0).sum()),
    RoundedOutMinutes = ('RoundedOutMinutes1', lambda x: (x > 0).sum()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the logical operations such as `(x > 0)` in your lambda functions are boolean arrays, thus `(x > 0).sum()` will return the sum over the boolean results, which is equivalent to the count of `True` instances in the resulting array.

If you want to return the sum over `x` when the condition is `True`, you can use: `lambda x: x[x > 0].sum()`

Comment: Thanks so much.  That did it. I get the boolean, but don't really understand the x[x ...  Will need to research that more. Appreciated.

Comment: The expression `x[x > 0]` uses boolean indexing, and means "return a subset of the array `x` in which all elements of `x` are greater than zero". This has more details: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays